# Chrome Dev Editor

Tags: google-chrome

I'd like to have Chrome Dev editor run inside a Chrome browser tab. Currently I'm opening the editor from the App launcher and alt-tabbing between it and the chrome browser, where I'm testing: ideally, I'd like my setup to feel more like an IDE and exist inside one window.

Is this possible, and can anyone tell me how to get this working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with the new [Chrome Packaged apps](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/apps). These apps are designed to be run outside of the browser's window since they have access to more things than a browser tab. Google is trying to make these apps behave more like native apps than browser apps.